# How do i open all the links for a given URL using java?

Tags: java, hyperlink, interface

Okay So I have the code to open up an URL using firebox. I'm just trying to find out how to open up all the links on that page, it can be done one at a time or all at once, but I just want to know. I can't seem to find this anywhere.

String url = "http://www.example.com";

```
    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {

            desktop.browse(new URI(url));

        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide some code you use to "open up an URL". What object type do you get ?

Comment: String url = "http://www.example.com";
        if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {

desktop.browse(new URI(url));

} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
}
        }else{
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: Code does not belong in the comments. If you want to add information, click on the "edit" below your question, add that code, and remember to format it using the `{}` button.